# Drag and dropped DLL throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget

We have an app A that has a reference to an assembly B that contains some static methods.  Assembly B is in the same Visual Studio solution as app A.

We want the users of our app A to be able to write plugins.  They build the plugin (at present) by creating a new Class Library solution in Visual Studio, getting the Nuget Package for app A, and adding a reference in their plugin solution to assembly B, so that the plugin code compiles.

They do not need to test their plugin, which is why the code just needs to compile, although it would be nice if they could debug their code when running it in app A.

Once their code has compiled, the DLL for the plugin is put in a share and given to a different team (bureaucracy I know) who put it with the rest of app A's DLLs.

I would like the plugin DLL to use the assembly B DLL that is with all of app A's DLLs.

When I run app A, the Activator class picks up the plugin DLL and correctly creates an instance, but as soon as one of the static methods from assembly B is called, the plugin throws a MissingMethodException.

Things I have tried:
The plugin solution definitely works fine if you create it and compile it within application A's Visual Studio solution.

App A uses framework .Net 4.5, assembly B uses framework .Net 4.0, I have tried building the plugin with both frameworks without success.

The "Specific Version" of the reference to assembly B in the plugin solution was false in all cases tested.

I would welcome immediate solutions to this problem but also broader architectural suggestions on how to get these plugins to work.  I apologise if there is a duplicate question of this, I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you can use "Dotpeek" to decompile dll and see if the method defination exactly matches.
It's a free software available to decompile dotnet libraries.
If you don't have access to .pdb file then i would recommend using "dotnet reflector",or "IL Spy" it will decompile without pdb files.

Also do make sure you are referencing project in visual studio not the output dll.

Comment: or ILSpy (which is free)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem as follows:

Although the plugin only directly used static methods in Assembly B, these static methods actually made a chain of calls to various OTHER assemblies.

Instead of just adding a reference to Assembly B in my plugin, I did a Nuget command:

```
Install-Package -Id AppA -ProjectName Plugin
```

And this downloaded the latest AppA to the packages folder and added a reference to EVERY dll of AppA.

Like before, it compiled, but this time when I dragged the plugin dll into the AppA bin folder, the plugin code ran without throwing an exception.